# Mysql read and change variable at the same time

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to shift some variables by one. I searched for the command for it but I couldn't find. If anybody knows it please help me.

Here is the code:

```
private int shiftNumbers(int number) 
{
    int newNumber = 0;
    string stm = "UPDATE devices SET number= @newNumber WHERE number>@number";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        con.Close();
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(rdr.Read()) {
              newNumber = rdr.GetInt32(1);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newNumber ", (newNumber-1));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        con.Close();
        return null;
    }
    con.Close();
    return 1;
}
```

I know this code useless but I show it for you to get the logic that I want to do.

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with this code.  I'm not even sure what it is you're *trying* to do.

Comment: Like @David said please explain WHAT you want with a clear example.

Comment: I know. I just tried to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong.

1. First, you read from the database, using a `select` statement;
2. Then you go over that result, your `rdr.Read()`;
3. Then you create a new command, updating the original record;
4. Move forward in your reader (`rdr`) and repeat from 2 until you are done.

What you are doing now is impossible. You can't get a result set from an `update`, just a count affected.

Or, if you can, let your update statement do the calculation (it seems it is only subtracting one from the original `number`, so why not do that in SQL?):

```
string stm = "UPDATE devices SET number = number - 1 WHERE number>@number";
```

Comment: The SQL statement is one statement, right? How much shorter do you want to have it? (From "Or, ..." is the second solution)

Comment: When I replied my answer , I couldn't read your post. I have noticed now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is really useless. In your update statement you are passing a parameter `@newNumber` bu not providing it. Closing the connection in `catch` block.

```
string stm = "UPDATE devices SET number= @newNumber WHERE number>@number";
```

First decide from where you are going to get the `@newNumber` value and then add that as parameter and use `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

If you want pass the other parameter as well in your method and use it like

```
   private int shiftNumbers(int number, int newNumber) 
    {
        //int newNumber = 0;
        string stm = "UPDATE devices SET number= @newNumber WHERE number>@number";
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, con);
                SqlParameter paramNumber = new SqlParameter("@number", SqlDbType.Int);
                paramNumber.Value = number;


               SqlParameter paramNewNumber = new SqlParameter("@newNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
               paramNewNumber.Value = newNumber;

               cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNumber);
               cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNewNumber);

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
        }



  //Rest of your code logic if any
   }
```

Comment: You are right. But I have to take the number value from same table. Thats why I can't assign newNumber